# Changing all links on page with js

Tags: javascript

I want to remove "/index.php" in all links on page

Example:

```
http://example.com/?hostname=sad2.cherobr.ru&path=/index.php/o-nas
```

change to:

```
http://example.com/?hostname=sad2.cherobr.ru&path=/o-nas
```

Comment: What about String.replace function?

Comment: Why use JS at all?

Answer (score 0):

with plain js

```
var allAnchors = document.querySelectorAll("a");
Array.prototype.slice.call( allAnchors ).forEach( function( el ){
  var href = el.getAttribute( "href" );
  el.setAttribute( "href", href.replace( "/index.php", "" ) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using replace function.

```js
console.log('http://example.com/?hostname=sad2.cherobr.ru&path=/index.php/o-nas'.replace('/index.php', ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the `replace("url","/index.php")` function like this.

```
var ref= document.getElementById("linkId").href;
document.getElementById("linkId").href= ref.replace("/index.php","");
```

For removing it from all links on the page.

```
var refs= document.getElementsByTagName(a);
for(i=0;i<refs.length;i++)
{
  refs[i].href= refs[i].href.replace("/index.php","");

}
```